# Grove connector SMD footprint dimensions

Tags: surface-mount, footprint

I'm creating layout for my PCB and I want to use Gvove connector in SMD package (http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/e/e0/3470120P1.pdf). But footprint from the datasheet doesnt have all the required dimensions. May be somebody knows the dimensions B,C,D [image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<rant>`
Amazing. How some engineers could indeed forget putting half of the critical dimensions here? How can Seeed publish this datasheet as if it was useful?
`</rant>`

Anyway... I made some research. It appears this same connector is used on some dev kit of TI called ["SimpleLink SensorTag Debugger DevPack"](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-devpack-debug) (dunno what it is exactly), which mentions Grove conectors in its marketing material. And the BOM lists the connector part number as 1125R-SMT-4P, which is the part number mentioned in the datasheet you linked and also given by Seeed on its [Open Parts Library catalog](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/OPLopen-parts-library-catalog-c-136_138/?ref=crumb). So I'm quite confident it is exactly the same.

So I downloaded the design files, loaded the gerber files in some gerber viewer tool, and measured the dimensions on their layout:

[image]

It gives: B=3.4mm, C=4mm, D=3.6mm.

Just noticed Hayman updated his answer. He doesn't obtain the same results, but most certainly, both layouts are appropriate. They just don't have the same clearances. Well, maybe you can buy these conectors, measure, and report back.

Comment: It might be that one of the manufacturers uses elongated pads or something similar. From the centre of the mounting pads to the centre of the signal pads measures the same at least (7.55 for me 7.5 for you)

Comment: @Hayman Yes, that's what I think too. I reworded my answer in this sense.

Comment: I still find it baffling some of the information that suppliers leave off sometimes. Or even worse, when you're looking at components on RS and they don't have the datasheets!

Comment: @Hayman I totally agree. But of course, it happens a lot with products from cheap manufacturers. If it was from Molex or Hirose, it sure wouldn't be lacking information in the datasheets. Also agree that RS (although not a cheap distributor) is quite bad at providing useful datasheets for fancy products.

Comment: I know its off topic. But where can I buy a reel of these. Seeed does not want to sell a reel to me due to some licencing issue. No use design with it if I can't source it.

Comment: @BertusKruger "Licensing issues" ?? How can they refuse to sell a reel of something they are able to sell single units of? Anyway, I don't really know. The Seed [datahseet](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/images/e/e0/3470120P1.pdf) indicates a company name: "Shenzhen NS-Tech co, ltd". Maybe you could try to find this source. Or ask Seeed. If they can't sell a reel, maybe they will be willing to give you information for another source.

Comment: @dim I manage to talk to the manufacturer(nstech.com.cn) and they can supply the components at USD0.15 with a MOQ of 3000.

Comment: @dim , USD0.15 is way above what SeeedStudio's OPL part cost is. The have them listed as USD0.06. But at least I have a source now.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging around I found the wiki page which has some eagle files for the boards.

From there I've managed to open the files and get the dimensions directly from their .brd files.

The sizes as determined from their eagle files.

B = 2.7mm
C = 4.6mm
D = 3.2mm

The board which I have taken the dimensions from is [this board here](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_LED_Matrix_Driver_v1.0) this was the only one on the wiki with a right angle surface mount and eagle files that looked correct

Edit: After a little more digging around in the eagle files it seems that they call the footprint 'HW4-SMD-2.0-90D'
This matches up with the [datasheet found here](https://easyeda.com/component/GROVE_CONNECTOR_SMD_90D42P_2_0-VhbtnFXe8).

Comment: But it isn't. Grove uses a proprietary connector.

Comment: Didn't realise that, thought it was just another Chinese company renaming a part that already exists. I'll edit my answer.